# detect button type in angular 2 material pagination

Tags: angular, pagination, material-design

I have the following line that generates pagination buttons

`<mat-paginator (page)="changed($event)" #paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]"></mat-paginator>`

and in change function i get 3 things

```
length,pageIndex & pageSize
```

but i want to know that wether 'next' button is pressed or 'previous' button is pressed.

Comment: You can store the current page index in a variable in your class, then check that against `pageIndex`.

Comment: can we directly get the 'next' or 'previous' ?

Comment: As far as i know, No.

Comment: Yes this is really a problem!! Since sometimes you just want to know which button is pressed, yes.. you can store the current index as 'previous index' and compare it. But this create extra state, which makes it hard to restore.